# Same function to two elements

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to optimize my code:

```
const img = document.querySelector("img.slider");
const h3 = document.querySelector("h3.slider");
const h4 = document.querySelector("h4.slider");
const h5 = document.querySelector("h5.slider");
const prev = document.querySelector(".prev");
const next = document.querySelector(".next");

let active = 0;
h3.innerHTML = people[active].description;
h4.innerHTML = people[active].name;
h5.innerHTML = people[active].profession;


const prevPerson=()=>{
    if(active==0){
        active=people.length
    }
    active--;
    img.src = people[active].img;
    h3.innerHTML = people[active].description;
    h4.innerHTML = people[active].name;
    h5.innerHTML = people[active].profession;

}

const nextPerson=()=>{
active++;
if(active===people.length){
    active=0;
}
img.src = people[active].img;
h3.innerHTML = people[active].description;
h4.innerHTML = people[active].name;
h5.innerHTML = people[active].profession;
}


prev.addEventListener('click', prevPerson);
next.addEventListener('click', nextPerson);
```

I think i would like to use same function for both prev and next but I don't know how to check if this is prev or next button. Any suggestions?

Comment: They each have their own respective classes (and presumably different textContent).

Comment: You can have value to each button and check the click by using Document.activeElement

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this
Pass the element to function

```
prev.addEventListener('click', prevOrNext(prev));
next.addEventListener('click', prevOrNext(next));
```

Then the prevOrNext fn looks like this

```
function PrevOrNext(elem) {
  if(elem === prev) {
    //Prev button code
  } else {
    //Next button code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the build in `event` for listeners, you can get the element in the function `e.target`. Using `data` in your buttons you can pass through if it's a forward or prev - I used 1 and -1. You can access these through the `e.target.dataset` property. Finally, since the handler is now the same for both, you can set it in a loop using the button's class.

```js
active = 0;
people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const prevNextPerson = (e) => {
  dir = Number(e.target.dataset.dir);
  active += dir;
  if (active == -1 && dir < 0) {
    active = people.length - 1
  } else if (active === people.length && dir > 0) {
    active = 0
  }
  console.log("Active: " + active);
  //img.src = people[active].img;
  // h3.innerHTML = people[active].description;
  //h4.innerHTML = people[active].name;
  //h5.innerHTML = people[active].profession;

}


const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-button');
for (btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', prevNextPerson);
}
```

```html
<button class='nav-button' data-dir="-1">Prev</button> <button class='nav-button' data-dir="1">Next</button>
```